# How to create multiple objects in the same function but without overwriting each other?

Tags: c++, pointers, variables, object

I'm trying to create an object in a function, but I am running into the problem that variable names have to be defined at runtime. Is there something I can do like with arrays that allows ne to dynamically create a variable in a function and preferably give it a different name from the one created when the function was called last?

***I'm working in C++

EDIT:
I can't give any code because I don't have any right now. All I have right now is pseudo code.

Basically, I'm trying to create a linked list, but the addNewItem() method that I want to use would require using the same method to create different objects.

EDIT:
Technically, we're not making a linklist, just more of a proof of concept to understand how they work.

EDIT: Here's the code:

```
#include "linklist.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct linklist
{
    Student * obj;
    linklist * next;
};

linklist * head;

int main()
{

}
void addStudent(char * newsdnt)
{
    if(!head){
            linklist * a = new linklist;
            a->obj = new Student(newsdnt);
            a->next = 0;
            head = a;
            return;
    }else{
            linklist * a = new linklist;
            a->obj = new Student(newsdnt);
            a->next = 0;
            if(!head->next){
                    head->next = a;  // Can only have one or two items in list
            }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a linked list - call new to create each new node and then add it to the list.

Smth like this:

```
void addStudent(char * newsdnt)
{
    linklist* a = new linklist;
    a.obj = new Student(newsdnt);
    a.next = 0;

    if( head == 0 ) {
        head = a;
    } else {
        linklist* whereToAdd = head;
        while( whereToAdd.next != 0 ) {
            whereToAdd = whereToAdd.next;
        }
        whereToAdd.next = a;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Luc:What exactly was changed for formatting to become correct?

Comment: I removed <pre><code> and added indentation. Otherwise, the first and last lines were left out of the code block (at least on my browser (Firefox 3)).

Comment: Yeap, the same was on IE6. So should I just indent all the lines of code with at least one space to make them look as preformatted?

Comment: You must indent your code with four spaces (or use the "code" button of the editor): http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help .

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to build a (singly) linked list is to add the new item at the front:

```
linklist *head = 0;

...
a->next = head;
head = a;
...
```

If it is acceptable to add items at the tail in O(N) time, then you scan the list each time to find the end.

```
linklist head;

...
a->next = 0;
item = &head;
while (item->next != 0)
    item = item->next;
item->next = a;
...
```

If you must add new items at the tail of the list in O(1) time, then keep a circular list, and a pointer to the tail of the list (so that `tail->next` is a pointer to the head of the list).  (The previous list structures could be called 'open ended'.)

```
linklist  root = { 0, &root };
linklist *tail = &root;

...
a->next = tail;
tail->next = a;
...
```

Beware: the termination conditions for iterating over the entire list (e.g. to find an item in the list) vary depending on the structure used (circular versus open-ended).

**Caveat**: untested code!

If you aren't sure what O(1) and O(N) means, then read up on 'Big O' notation.

Comment: Circular list may be difficult to manupulate. If "add to end at O(n)" is needed it's often better to use an open-ended list with a service root element storing addresses of the first and last elements.

Comment: Circular lists are relatively standard in doubly-linked lists.  There's no big problem with singly-linked lists either; the termination condition ceases to be 'a->next == 0' and becomes 'a->next == start', not a huge difference and perfectly systematic (just like open-ended lists).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a vector:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
void foo()
{
    vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(3);
    cout << v[0] + v[1] << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you need `N` objects of some type `T`:Arrays are very much present in C++. So is the STL which provides you with a host of oppertunities. You need to define how you will want to access and use these objects -- that influences the choice of your container. But can you post some code so that our answers are a little less vague (and more helpful to you)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you want but is sounds like you could use  [Multiset](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/stl/multiset/start).

Please provide more details, and I might be able to provide more help.

Answer (score 0):

For starters I would suggest you rename your linkedlist struct to node and add a new linked list struct that holds the head, and (maybe) current / tail pointers. You should then implement methods in this class / struct that will allow you to manipulate it.

What you're missing at the moment is a method that will traverse the list (recursively getting the next pointer until you're at the end) and return a pointer to the last element. Once you have that, you can set the next pointer of that element to your newly created object.